# Индекс находится вне границ массива C#, SQLite

Tags: c#, массивы, sqlite

Добрый чудный день!
Имею SQLite базу следующего содержания.
[image: sqlite]

Имею следующий C# код для чтения данных с базы:

```
private void playersCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string curr = playersCombobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
    SQLiteConnection sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=db.db");
    SQLiteCommand sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM players WHERE nickname='"+curr+"';", sqlConnection);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SQLiteDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        ageLabel.Content = "Возраст: "+sqlReader["age"].ToString();
        sexLabel.Content = "Пол: "+ sqlReader["sex"].ToString();
        countryLabel.Content = "Страна: "+ sqlReader["country"].ToString();
    }
    sqlReader.Close();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Он работает хорошо и со своими функциями справляется.
Однако, если я хочу из SQliteReader взять еще один элемент базы, к примеру элемент "sniper", получаю следующий код:

```
string curr = playersCombobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
SQLiteConnection sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=db.db");
SQLiteCommand sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM players WHERE nickname='"+curr+"';", sqlConnection);
sqlConnection.Open();
SQLiteDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    ageLabel.Content = "Возраст: "+sqlReader["age"].ToString();
    sexLabel.Content = "Пол: "+ sqlReader["sex"].ToString();
    countryLabel.Content = "Страна: "+ sqlReader["country"].ToString();
    sniperLabel.Content = "Снайпер:" + sqlReader["sniper"].ToString();
}
sqlReader.Close();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

В результате выполнения кода получаю ошибку:

[image: error]

Которая ведет на строчку

```
sniperLabel.Content = "Снайпер:" + sqlReader["sniper"].ToString();
```

Почему так происходит и что я делаю не так?

Comment: а попробуйте переставить местами чтение country и sniper

Comment: @vitidev это не решает моей проблемы

Comment: тогда идей больше нет. а эта идея была в том, что ридер не материализует строку, а читает последовательно по колонкам и не может вернутся назад и дойдя до country он уже прошел мимо sniper

Comment: А вы пробовали проходить по коду дебагером и смотреть, что у Вас там вообще содержится? Поставьте контрольную точку перед строкой, в которой выводится ошибка и запустите программу. Когда дойдет до точки, выделите ваш sqlReader и нажмите Shift+F10(или ПКМ -> окно quickWatch) и посмотрите, что у Вас там вообще находится. По ошибке, никакого sniper в выборке и sqlReader нету.

Comment: да, конечно пробовал. Однако, все что мне показывает дебагер - кол-во элементов в SQLiteReader. Их 8 штук, ровно как в базе

Comment: Перейдите дальше по веткам, там должны быть перечислены имена полей в строковых представлениях во время выборки у самих элементов, у меня к примеру по пути: sqlReader -> ResultView -> [0] -> Non-public -> _fieldNameLookup ->_fieldNames. Для примера вот скрин: http://imgur.com/LD1kaWs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны две причины ошибки.

1. В SQLiteStudio вы смотрите одну БД, в которой есть колонка sniper, а в приложении подключена другая БД, в которой такой колонки нет.
   Это весьма частая ошибка при разработке: к приложению подключена другая БД.
2. Опечатка в названии колонки sniper: например, буква 'е' русская. Не найдя нужную колонку, провайдер выдаёт IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но первый вариант был правильный.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM players
Не пишите так. Всегда указывайте, какие именно поля требуются вам в выборке. 
Ошибка по приведенному вами примеру указывает, что "sniper" все же отсутствует в полученном наборе данных. К тому же, NULL по-умолчанию и безусловный вызов ToString() явно приведут к еще одной ошибке.

Пересмотрите ограничения в таблице.
Перепишите запрос.

```
string curr = playersCombobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
SQLiteConnection sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=db.db");
SQLiteCommand sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT TOP 1 age, sex, country, sniper FROM players WHERE nickname='"+curr+"';", sqlConnection);
sqlConnection.Open();
SQLiteDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlReader.Read())
{

     ageLabel.Content = "Возраст: "+sqlReader[0].ToString();
    sexLabel.Content = "Пол: "+ sqlReader[1].ToString();
    countryLabel.Content = "Страна: "+ sqlReader[2].ToString();
    sniperLabel.Content = "Снайпер:" + sqlReader[3].ToString();
}
sqlReader.Close();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Однако, ошибка сохраняется при явном указании полей в запросе

Comment: Если более детально: ошибка, в вашем случае говорит о том, что значение, которое вы пытаетесь получить по-имени отсутствует в полученной выборке. Если это не так, то попробуйте задать псевдоним в запросе для поля sniper.

Comment: я, если честно, не совсем вас понимаю.

Comment: попробуйте сделать, как я описал в добавленном примере

Comment: получаю ошибку ошибку синтаксиса в SQL запросе

Comment: какая ошибка? опишите. Поправил запрос. забыл про запятые в списке

Comment: near "1" - syntax error

Comment: @crystal убери TOP 1

Comment: проблема с "индексом" снова актуальна